# How to create a private registry in containerd using ctr command?

Tags: docker, containerd, ctr

I am new to containerd. Please help me out.

In docker to deploy a private registry, we have the below command

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name registry 
-v "$(pwd)"/certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key
 -p 443:443 registry:2
```

How to deploy a private registry using containerd using the ctr command?

Please help